# Image Viewer (eog) causes lightdm to restart

Tags: unity, lightdm, crash, eog

When I open an image and without zooming, try to drag to any border (which is ofcourse, by mistake), `eog` closes and a black screen appears** that says `lightdm` is starting, and lands me in login screen.

I have no idea why.

- Is anyone facing the same problem ?
- **Is there a solution?**

I tried reinstalling `eog` and `lightdm`.

---

As suggested by @Ferran Rigual, I executed

```
eog ~/Compiler_Design/SAM_5069.JPG --g-fatal-warnings 2>~/out.txt
```

and out.txt contained:

`(eog:3899): Gdk-WARNING **: eog: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.`

After logging in, I can see `_usr_bin_eog.1000.crash` and `_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash` created in `/var/crash`.  I don't know what to do with crash files .

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for a while, I filed a bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/1450812

This problem in fixed in Ubuntu 14.04,  but is present in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `eog` using the console and update your question with the output that appears when the problem is reproduced. That, of course, if you can still read it after the new login.

UPDATE: As stated in its manual page (`man eog`), maybe you will get more info using the flag `--g-fatal-warnings` .

Comment: i tried `eog filename > ~/out.txt`. When the problem occurred as expected, I logged in to open out.txt and found that it is blank.

Comment: is there any way to log all events including _file read_, _file opened_ etc ?

Comment: Answer updated, but I would recommend you to execute it like `eog filename 2> ~/out.txt`, since the error channel is the second one.

Comment: Yeah. I found something that might interest you. See updated uestion